# Swift: How to retrieve different type and named primary keys from generic memory stores?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have two protocols and two objects that implement them. One object uses name:String as its primary key, the other uses code:Int.

```
protocol AlphaProtocol{
    var name:String {get set}
    init(name: String)
}

protocol BetaProtocol{
    var code: Int {get set}
    init(code:Int)
}

class AlphaObject: AlphaProtocol{
    var name: String

    required init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }

}

class BetaObject: BetaProtocol{
    var code: Int

    required init(code: Int){
        self.code = code
    }
}
```

Right now, to store the these objects I use two different memory stores that implement two different protocols, one for each kind of object.

```
protocol AlphaStoreProtocol{
    func addObject(object anObject: AlphaProtocol)
    func getObject(name aName:String)->AlphaProtocol?
    func removeObject(name aName: String)
}

protocol BetaStoreProtocol{
    func addObject(object anObject: BetaProtocol)
    func getObject(code aCode:Int)->BetaProtocol?
    func removeObject(code aCode: Int)
}

class AlphaStore{

    fileprivate var objects = [AlphaProtocol]()

    func addObject(object anObject: AlphaProtocol){
        if getObject(name: anObject.name) == nil{
            objects.append(anObject)
        }
    }

    func getObject(name aName:String)->AlphaProtocol?{
        for o in objects{
            if o.name == aName{
                return o
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func removeObject(name aName: String){
        self.objects = self.objects.filter({$0.name != aName})
    }
}

class BetaStore: BetaStoreProtocol{

    fileprivate var objects = [BetaProtocol]()

    func addObject(object anObject: BetaProtocol){
        if getObject(code: anObject.code) == nil{
            objects.append(anObject)
        }
    }

    func getObject(code aCode:Int)->BetaProtocol?{
        for o in objects{
            if o.code == aCode{
                return o
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func removeObject(code aCode: Int){
        self.objects = self.objects.filter({$0.code != aCode})
    }
}
```

Test Code using two tailor made stores.

```
let alpha = AlphaObject(name: "Alpha")
let beta = BetaObject(code: 12345)

let alphaStore = AlphaStore()
let betaStore = BetaStore()

alphaStore.addObject(object: alpha)
if (alphaStore.getObject(name: alpha.name) != nil){
    print("alpha object has been added to alphaStore")
}
alphaStore.removeObject(name: alpha.name)
if (alphaStore.getObject(name: alpha.name) == nil){
    print("alpha object has been removed from alphaStore")
}

betaStore.addObject(object: beta)
if (betaStore.getObject(code: beta.code) != nil){
    print("beta object has been added to betaStore")
}
betaStore.removeObject(code: beta.code)
if (betaStore.getObject(code: beta.code) == nil){
    print("beta object has been removed from betaStore")
}
```

The goal: using a single generic class for both the stores but I'm stuck because the two objects use two different primary keys (different type and **different name**) and I can't simply force a generic "Id" as the primary key in the objects. One has to be named "name" and the other "code".

Is there a way to write the getObject and removeObject methods to accept both kind of objects?

```
protocol GenericStoreProtocol{
    associatedtype T
    func addObject(object anObject: T)
    // func getObject()->T  // One object use a name:String, the other code:Int as its primary key!
    // func removeObject()  // One object use a name:String, the other code:Int as its primary key!
}

class GenericStore<T>: GenericStoreProtocol{

    fileprivate var objects = [T]()

    func addObject(object anObject: T){
        objects.append(anObject)
    }

    // ...
}

let genericAlphaStore = GenericStore<AlphaProtocol>()
let genericBetaStore = GenericStore<BetaProtocol>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't simply force a generic "Id" as the primary key in the objects.

Yep, you totally can if you use a single protocol instead of two unrelated ones (`AlphaProtocol` and `BetaProtocol`).

```
protocol KeyedObject {
    associatedtype PrimaryKey : Equatable
    var key: PrimaryKey { get }
}
```

Just make your objects conform to this protocol; they can declare whatever equatable type you require for the key, they just have to provide some way to access it.

```
class AlphaObject: KeyedObject {
    typealias PrimaryKey = String
    var name: String

    required init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    var key: String {
        return self.name
    }
}
```

Then you can use a straightforward generic class that contains only objects you provided:

```
class GenericStore<T : KeyedObject> {

    fileprivate var objects = [T]()

    func addObject(object anObject: T){
        objects.append(anObject)
    }

    func getObject(key: T.PrimaryKey) -> T? {
        for o in objects{
            if o.key == key {
                return o
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To generalize the problem, we need a store that can:

- add items of any types (or ones we specify)
- look up and delete items by id
- use the correct id property for different stored objects

First, I'd create a protocol called `Storable` which has an `identifier` computed property. This should be of type `Equatable` as we will eventually be using equality comparisons when looking up objects by id in our `Store`.

```
protocol Storable {
    associatedtype Identifier: Equatable
    var identifier: Identifier { get }
}
```

We can now define the classes of the objects we are going to store (`AlphaObject` and `BetaObject`). Both of these classes should conform to their own protocol as well as the `Stored` protocol. Here is where you'd define what property should be used as the identifier. For `AlphaObject` it's `name` and for `BetaObject` it's `code`. These can be read-only computed properties that return the values of `name` and `code` respectively.

```
protocol AlphaProtocol {
    var name: String { get set }
    init(name: String)
}

protocol BetaProtocol {
    var code: Int { get set }
    init(code: Int)
}


class AlphaObject: AlphaProtocol, Storable {
    typealias Identifier = String

    internal var identifier: Identifier {
        return self.name
    }

    var name: String

    required init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

}

class BetaObject: BetaProtocol, Storable {
    typealias Identifier = Int

    internal var identifier: Identifier {
        return self.code
    }

    var code: Int

    required init(code: Int){
        self.code = code
    }
}
```

Finally, our `Store` will take any objects that are `Storable` and will access, insert, and delete based on `T`'s specified `identifier`.

```
class Store<T: Storable> {
    fileprivate var objects = [T]()

    func addObject(object: T) {
        if getObject(identifier: object.identifier) == nil {
            objects.append(object)
        }
    }

    func getObject(identifier: T.Identifier) -> T? {
        for o in objects {
            if o.identifier == identifier {
                return o
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func removeObject(identifier: T.Identifier) {
        self.objects = self.objects.filter({$0.identifier != identifier})
    }
}
```

The full code with tests!

```
protocol Storable {
    associatedtype Identifier: Equatable
    var identifier: Identifier { get }
}

protocol AlphaProtocol {
    var name: String { get set }
    init(name: String)
}

protocol BetaProtocol {
    var code: Int { get set }
    init(code: Int)
}


class AlphaObject: AlphaProtocol, Storable {
    typealias Identifier = String

    internal var identifier: Identifier {
        return self.name
    }

    var name: String

    required init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

}

class BetaObject: BetaProtocol, Storable {
    typealias Identifier = Int

    internal var identifier: Identifier {
        return self.code
    }

    var code: Int

    required init(code: Int){
        self.code = code
    }
}

class Store<T: Storable> {
    fileprivate var objects = [T]()

    func addObject(object: T) {
        if getObject(identifier: object.identifier) == nil {
            objects.append(object)
        }
    }

    func getObject(identifier: T.Identifier) -> T? {
        for o in objects {
            if o.identifier == identifier {
                return o
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func removeObject(identifier: T.Identifier) {
        self.objects = self.objects.filter({$0.identifier != identifier})
    }
}


/* Tests */
let alpha = AlphaObject(name: "Alpha")
let beta = BetaObject(code: 12345)

let alphaStore = Store<AlphaObject>()
let betaStore = Store<BetaObject>()

alphaStore.addObject(object: alpha)
if (alphaStore.getObject(identifier: alpha.name) != nil){
    print("alpha object has been added to alphaStore")
}
alphaStore.removeObject(identifier: alpha.name)
if (alphaStore.getObject(identifier: alpha.name) == nil){
    print("alpha object has been removed from alphaStore")
}

betaStore.addObject(object: beta)
if (betaStore.getObject(identifier: beta.code) != nil){
    print("beta object has been added to betaStore")
}
betaStore.removeObject(identifier: beta.code)
if (betaStore.getObject(identifier: beta.code) == nil){
    print("beta object has been removed from betaStore")
}
```

Comment: Upvote for you because your answer is about the same as the one Kevin provided one hour ago. Thank you both. I'm testing it and it works!

Comment: No problem. Best of luck! :)